# Centered slides when slidesPerView number larger than contained slides

Tags: swiper.js

In cases where we have dynamic content to be added. Is it possible to have slides centered before the first row of slidesPerView is reached?

For example, have 1, 2 or 3 slides centered when slidersPerView is set to 4 like shown:

[image]